# logical shift in c understanding

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I'm currently trying to understand how this logical shift works.
Given the formula:

```
int logicalShift(int x, int n){
    int mask = x >> 31 << 31 >> n << 1;
    return mask^ (x>>n);
}
```

Test run of  `x = 0x87654321 and n = 4.` gave  `logicalShift(x,n) = 0x08765432`

Here, I know that x in binary is `1000 0111 0110 0101 0100 0011 0010 0001` and following the mask process,

x >> 31 is `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001`

and << 31 to that is `1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`

and >> n to that is `0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`

and << 1 to that is `0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`.

doing `mask^ (x>>n)` means doing XOR to `0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` with `0000 1000 0111 0110 0101 0100 0011 0010` which results in `0001 1000 0111 0110 0101 0100 0011 0010` which would be 0x18765432.

Have I done the shifting wrong?

Comment: Notice that `0x87654321` does set the sign bit of a 32-bit signed integer; the behaviour of right shift is implementation-defined; if the left shift causes the sign bit to be changed, the behaviour is undefined. You **must** use `unsigned int` for well-defined logical shifting behaviour. This function is utterly b0rken as it is.

Comment: Shifting *signed* numbers into overflow is undefined behaviour. Use `unsigned int` for bit fiddling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you've done the shifting wrong. When `>>`'s left operand is a signed integer, compilers will typically perform an *arithmetic* right shift, not a logical right shift. This is hinted at in the function name: if `>>` performed a logical right shift, it could just return `x >> n` directly. The point of the function is to implement a logical right shift by using arithmetic right shift.

What arithmetic right shift means is that when right-shifting, the left bits are not filled with zeroes, but are filled with whatever the left-most bit (the sign bit) was. Therefore:

> x >> 31 is `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001`

x >> 31 is actually `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`.

Comment: `x >> 31` has implementation-defined behaviour.

Comment: Yes, not guaranteed by C standard (some languages define strictly shifting, but cost more)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Hence my use of the word "typically". As this question is not tagged language-lawyer, it does not benefit the OP to go into this in any more detail.

Comment: There is no "typical" implementation. If none is tagged it should be taken as asking about the language. However, for example GCC *does* define these.

Answer (score 2):

This excerpt is wrong:

```
int logicalShift(int x, int n){
    int mask = x >> 31 << 31 >> n << 1;
    return mask^ (x>>n);
}
```

The behaviour of `x >> 31` when `x` is negative is implementation-defined. The `<< 31` with negative value or if it changes the sign bit has undefined behaviour. It will work as if it did logical shift under very strict assumptions:

- the width of `int` is 32 bits
- the signed integers have 2's complement as their internal representation
- that the behaviour of right-shift of negative numbers does *arithmetic right shift*,
- that the behaviour of left-shift of negative numbers is defined as if the 2's complement representation shifted left logically.

Such does not follow from the C standard. However, it would behave as expected on any GCC target platform where `int` is 32-bits wide as GCC specifies the 3 last ones as true.

---

This code is wrong because to do a proper logical shift, one should to use `unsigned` values. However, to get these *back* to a signed value is tricky - not that it would usually be needed.

This function has completely defined behaviour for logical right shift given that the value of `n` is within the limits (non-negative and less than the width of `x` in bits):

```
unsigned int logicalShift(unsigned int x, int n) {
    return x >> n;
}
```

As it does one expression only, we notice that using a function for such an operation is not needed.

Comment: Code relying on implementation-defined behaviour or documented extensions is not wrong, just not fully portable. It is actively harmful to pretend that it is wrong and use that as an excuse to not answer the OP's question.

Comment: @hvd however we do not know if the left shift has defined behaviour even on the OP's implementation. It is just all assumptions everywhere.

Comment: @hvd I get a lot a bug cause people use signed integer with bit shifting, that a real problem with real bug. It's not "intellectual masturbation". bit shifting is miss understood by a lot of people. Your comment is very rude !

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thank you for the effort you've made in your edit, I very much appreciate it. DV retracted.

Comment: @Stargateur There are a lot of real bugs that cause real problems in a lot of real code related to bit shifting, and if the code would be likely to fail on any real implementation in current use, I wouldn't even have hesitated to include that in my answer. But it won't be with the code in the question, at least not for the function arguments in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`x >> 31 is 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001` No, its wrong. your `x` is `signed` integer and `num` is `0x87654321` that means last `31st bit` is `1 or set`, so when you do right shifting that `sign` bit get copied, that result `x` as `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`

To get expected output take `num` as `unsigned` type.

```
int logicalShift(unsigned int x, int n){
   /* some code */
}
```

Note that its implementation dependent as If your processor supports **arithmetic right shifting** then `last bit(sign bit)` gets copied into remaining bytes and if its a logical right shifting then it won't.

Comment: The behaviour of right-shifting negative signed integers is *implementation-defined*.